# How to ensure decorator's argument "target" extends an interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, interface, decorator

I'm learning typescript 2 and playing around decorators and generic T.
Is it possible for a Class decorator to ensure his target extends a specific interface ?

Like so (this code doesn't work) :

```
interface IAction {}

function Action(options?:any) {
    return function(target:<T extends IAction>) {}
}

@Action()
export class CreateTodoAction implements IAction {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface Action {
  kind: string;
}

function action(options?: {}) {
    return function<T extends new(...args: {}[]) => Action>(target: T) {}
}

@action()
export class CreateTodoAction implements Action {
  kind = 'create';
}
```

Its worth noting that since the `implements` clause is optional in TypeScript, and since the decorator enforces that its target class creates instances that satisfy the interface anyway, there is no real reason to use it in the class definition itself. Just a matter of style, but it feels repetitive.

Comment: Thanks Aluan.
I tried your code and realise that typescript doesn't throw an error if CreateTodoAction does not implement `interface Action`.

My goal is to force implementing Action interface if `@action` decorator is used. Is it possible with typescript ?

Comment: Yes it does. The problem is that your interface is empty. There is no way to require the `implements` clause, if that is what you mean, because the type system is structural. This requires that the `interface`'s members be implemented which is the exact same thing in a structural type system.

Comment: @David I understand your goal and that is exactly what this does.

Comment: The next step for me was to create a method decorator which only accept a class implementing `Action interface`.

`function on<T extends new(...args: {}[]) => Action>(action:T):any {
    return function(target, key, descriptor){}
}`

That's fit to my needs, thanks for your time ;)

Comment: Mhh, that's working, if i use a `class FalseTodoAction` not implementing `Action` and passing it to the `@on` method decorator. Then if i set `name` property to that `class FalseTodoAction`, typescript does not throw error.

But if don't want to "just" check structure but Really ensure that the first arg of `@on` decorator is a `CreateTodoAction` constructor ? what i understood is `new(...args: {}[]) => Action` is telling to compiler "i want to get an object implementing the structure of an Action". What about : "I want to get an object equals to CreateTodoAction constructor" ?

Comment: @David to enforce subclass constraint, put the constraint on the static side of the type argument. Ex: `return function<T extends CreateTodoAction>(target: T) {}` will enforce decorator is a subtype of `CreateToDoAction`. It is still structural, but you can make it "nominalesque" by adding a protected member to the base class.

Comment: @David you can create your method decorator by stipulating the constraint on the instance level since that's the first object that gets passed to it. The type for that function would look a lot like what you have in your original question just with `key` and `descriptor?` arguments following `target`

Comment: `function on(options) { return <T extends Action, K extends keyof T>(target: T, key: K, descriptor?) => {...}; }`